# Custom method query findOne($id) for Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm sorry to aske this question (for it would be for dummy). I want to get one entity with my custom method ( `myFindOne($id)` ) where `$id` is that entity ID and I try that (no success):

```
public function myFindOne($id)
    {
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('u')
        ->from('IballotCmsBundle:User', 'u')
        ->where('u.id = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);
        return $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: You can use too `findOneBy(['id'=>$id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few other methods similar to `getResult` for example `getOneOrNullResult` which returns one result or null if any row was found.

```
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('u')
    ->from('IballotCmsBundle:User', 'u')
    ->where('u.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id);
    return $qb->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```